# Why the code segment is creating memory leak?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-observable

I am using http service to get user data from UserService. When i am subsscribing to the observable it is creating a memory leak. In the network tab of developer console it is visible that infinite http requests are being made.

tried to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy() method, but no luck.

user.service.ts

```
getCurrentUserDetails(){
    return this.http.get<User>(`${this.config.apiUrl}/user/me`);
  }
```

navbar.component.ts

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  user: User;
  userDetailsSubs: Subscription;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  isLoggedIn() {
    const currentUser: User = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    if (currentUser) {
      this.userDetailsSubs = this.userService.getCurrentUserDetails()
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.user = data;
          }
          , error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      //this.userDetailsSubs.unsubscribe();
      return true;
    }
    else
      return false;
  }
  logout() {
    this.authenticationService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.userDetailsSubs.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

navbar.component.html

```
<div class="sticky-top mb-3">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-danger justify-content-center p-3 mb-3" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn()">
    ..............
  </nav>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-danger p-3 mb-5" *ngIf="isLoggedIn()">
      .
      .
      .
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isLoggedIn()` function is triggered from template on change detection. Add `isLogged` property to your component and set it from ngOnInit to avoid multiple calls.

```
isLogged: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
  const currentUser: User = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    if (currentUser) {
      this.userDetailsSubs = this.userService.getCurrentUserDetails()
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.isLogged = true;
            this.user = data;
          }
          , error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }
    else
      this.isLogged = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. No more infinite http calls. But the problem is, after login the navbar state is not changing. Page needs to be refreshed for changing navbar state and loading user innformation.

Comment: @DusayantaPrasad `authenticationService.currentUserValue` changes over the time of component life. You could create `currentUser` as Observable and subscribe to it inside navbar component.

Comment: Although the answer is accepted and the solution is absolutely fine. Alternatively, you can use Angular pipe. To understand the impact of calling function in templates and solution, visit the following link - https://blog.angularindepth.com/tiny-angular-pipe-to-make-any-function-memoizable-f6c8fa917f2f

Answer (score 2):

Create a property in your class, say `isLoggedInFlag`.'

under your `isLoggedIn()` method, set it to true under subscription.

Have your view like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-danger justify-content-center p-3 mb-3" *ngIf="!isLoggedInFlag">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-danger p-3 mb-5" *ngIf="isLoggedInFlag">
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call method like this on HTML.

```
*ngIf="isLoggedIn()"
```

it'll continuously execute this method.